# How to select a value from one column based on the max value of another column and if that's the same, use the max value of another column

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say I have this table:

```
KEY |  PID  |  ID   |  YEAR
___________________________
 1  |  123  | 999   |  2018
 2  |  123  | 999   |  2017
 3  |  123  | 999   |  2016
 4  |  456  | 888   |  2018
 5  |  456  | 999   |  2018
 6  |  456  | 777   |  2018
```

I want to return the unique `KEY` value and corresponding `PID` by querying whichever row has the latest `YEAR` for that specific `PID`. If two `PIDs` have the same `YEAR`, it should check which one has the latest `ID`.

For example, the expected result would return:

```
1  |  123  
5  |  456
```

As you can see, `1` is returned because it has the latest year between the rest of the `IDs` and 5 is returned because although they're all the same `YEAR`, it has the highest `ID` value.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM yourtable WHERE year = (SELECT MAX(year) FROM yourtable))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by pid order by year desc id desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Another method, assuming `id` is unique is:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id = (select maxt2.id) keep (dense_rank first order by t2.id desc)
              from t t2
              where t2.pid = t.pid 
              order by t2.year desc
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  Key, PID
FROM table
WHERE [YEAR] = (SELECT MAX([YEAR]) FROM dbo.Ptable) 
AND ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM table)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT T.KEY,T.PID  
FROM T INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT PID,MAX(ID) MAXID
  FROM T
  GROUP BY PID
) T2 ON T2.MAXID = T.ID 
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT PID,MAX(YEAR) AS YID
  FROM T
  GROUP BY PID
) T3 ON T3.YID = T.YEAR
ORDER BY T.KEY
```

sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b30e1/28